# Accessing Enterprise Keywords in XSLT

Tags: document-library, xslt, enterprise-keywords

I am trying to put together a custom tag cloud in SharePoint 2010 using Enterprise Keywords as the data source instead of the built-in tags.

I've found numerous methods to display and build the tag cloud, but my issue is with getting a handle to the Enterprise Keywords data from the relevant library.

I'm using custom XSL templates within the ContentQueryMain.xsl to build the tag cloud, and part of this process is to connect to the media library and extract the keywords from each item.  It works perfectly when I build the cloud using a simple text field such as Title, but when I try to use the TaxKeyword field or the hidden note field TaxKeyTaxHTField it returns nothing.  I've experimented with other Note-type field like Keywords and it still returns no values.

Can anyone give me any clues on how to retrieve the values of any of the fields listed above, or a Note-type field in general in XSLT?